# Missing LoggingHandler in Enterprise Library 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, enterprise-library

I have been experimenting with both ELMAH and the EL 5.0.  I may go to ELMAH as it is a bit easier to deal with for an internal-only project, but this has been bothering me.  I tried setting up the EL 5.0 Exception Handling block in conjunction with the logging block, but was unable to configure a Logging Handler.

From what I understand I should see a Wrap, Replace, Custom and Logging handler.  The Logging portion however is missing.  Any tips on getting it working would be great.  Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the config tool is not finding the Logging Handler dll. Download it from [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging/) and place it where the rest of EntLib dll's are.

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up just going with Elmah instead for my logging.  Im liking that there is less configuration needed.